# Writing a factory for classes that have required arguments

Tags: php, factory-pattern

I understand the concept of factory pattern such that you give it something it spits out something of the same template back so if I gave a factory class apple, I expect to get many apples back with out having to instantiate a new apple ever time.

what if that apple has a required argument of seed, or multiple required arguments of seed, step and leaf? how do you use factory pattern here?

that is how do I use factory pattern to instantiate this:

```
$apple = new Apple($seed, $stem, $leaf);
```

Comment: Well, it (or another factory) instantiates `Seed`s, `Stem`s & `Leave`s? Factories are by no means limited to instantiate but one class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is shown bellow and fully documented. This factory works.

```
<?php
/**
 * This class is responsible for two core things:
 * 
 * One registering the dependencies and two creating
 * new instances of classes that you pass in as strings.
 * 
 * Your data structure needs to be a function that retruns and array
 * which is then used in the register_dependencies() function.
 * 
 * You would register the dependencies before you actually use this class
 * as you would a singleton.
 * 
 * The data structure is as such:
 * 
 * <code>
 * $array = array(
 *     // This is a class that takes no parameters.
 *     'class_name' => array(),
 * 
 *     // This is a class which takes in parameters.
 *     'class_name' => array(
 *         'params' => array(
 *             'params1',
 *             'params2'
 *             'optionalParams3'
 *         )
 *     ),
 * );
 * </code>
 *
 * You could then call the function, in this case foo() that returns this 
 * array as such:
 *
 * <code> 
 * AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::register_dependencies(foo());
 * </code>
 * 
 * Then else where you could do:
 * 
 * <code>
 * $object = AisisCore_Factory_Pattern::create('class_name');
 * $object->class_names_method();
 * </code>
 * 
 * And there ya go, you have created a class with its dependencies.
 * 
 * 
 * @author Adam Balan
 *
 */
class AisisCore_Factory_Pattern {

    /**
     * @var AisisCore_Factory_Pattern
     */
    protected static $_class_instance;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $_dependencies;

    /**
     * Create a new instance of the class assuming one
     * does not already exist.
     */
    public static function get_instance(){
        if(self::$_class_instance == null){
            $_class_instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$_class_instance;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new instance of a class with its dependencies.
     * 
     * We expect there to be a class, we expect there to be dependcies
     * already in the protected class level variable _dependencies and we
     * expect that class to be in the array of depdencies.
     * 
     * If it is not we throw an error.
     * 
     * If the class has arguments we populate the classes params with the arguments.
     * and if not we create a new instance of it.
     * 
     * @param string $class
     * @throws AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception
     */
    public static function create($class){
        if(empty($class)){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('Class cannot be empty.');
        }

        if(!isset(self::$_dependencies)){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('There is no dependencies arraty created. 
                Please create one and register it.');   
        }

        if(!isset(self::$_dependencies[$class])){
            throw new AisisCore_Exceptions_Exception('This class does not exist in the dependecies array!');
        }

        if(isset(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params'])){
            $new_class =  new $class(implode(', ', self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']));
            return $new_class;
        }else{
            $new_class = new $class();
            return $new_class;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register a new dependencie which is of type array.
     * 
     * @param array $array
     */
    public static function register_dependencies($array){
        self::$_dependencies = $array;
    }

}
```

Out of this class the most crucial part is the if statement in the create method:

```
if(isset(self::$_dependencies[$class]['params'])){
        $new_class =  new $class(implode(', ', self::$_dependencies[$class]['params']));
        return $new_class;
    }else{
        $new_class = new $class();
        return $new_class;
    }
```

We check the array for any params and if there are some we implode and glue together by a comma.